# Blank screen before and after the UIWebview load and next view load iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have two view controllers. In first view controller, I click a button and a webview loads. Before loading web view, it shows a black screen and it goes immediately and the webviews load. Again, when I go from my webview to another view controller, I see the same black screen comes and goes immediately.

PS : This code is not written by me, and it's a little messy so I am not able to paste code here.

Please let me know if you can think of any proper reasoning why its happening and how can I resolve it?

Is there any way i can check for number of view controllers in the stack?  Because sometimes instead of black screen it shows some previously loaded screen

This is the code used to remove all the view controller from stack -

```
UIViewController *vc = self.presentingViewController;
    while (vc.presentingViewController) {
        vc = vc.presentingViewController;

    }

    [vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

But still i can see some random screen from the app, comes up instead of black screen before my webview loads.

Any suggestions are welcomed. Thanks!!

Comment: Is there anything else you can post? Even just a couple of snippets where you think the problem might be?

Comment: Are you set the WebView Viewcontroller color = black?

Comment: without seeing code this question is hard to answer.

Comment: Code is total mess... But i believe it could be because of some view controllers in stack. Because sometimes instead of black screen it shows some previously loaded screen.

Answer (score 0):

Set in InterfaceBuilder or code white background color for UIWebView.

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    webViewInstance.opaque = NO;
    webViewInstance.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    //your remaining code here
}
```

Comment: No, i still see black screen, before my webview loads.